# Retrieving a photo using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I uploaded a photo to my own facebook profile, and made it public. Then I gave *user_photos* and *friends_photos* permission to my own app, and received the access token. I executed this call from my browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/*my_id*/photos?access_token=*access_token*
```

The response is an empty data set:

```
{
   "data": [
   ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong? This seems it should be so simple but not sure what I am screwing up. I would be grateful for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the user albums first to get the album id's,

```
https://graph.facebook.com/*my_id*/albums?access_token=*access_token*
```

so with the album id you can call:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/*album_id*/photos?access_token=*access_token*
```

this will return all the photos inside the album.